# How do I produce a ZIP of my source using Gradle?

Tags: gradle, zip, software-distribution

I'm converting a relatively small project from Ant to Gradle. I expect to reduce the number of lines in the build script by approximately 75%!

One thing the Ant build does is to produce a source ZIP (i.e. a ZIP of the whole project, with certain bits removed - ./build, various Eclipse folders, etc.) Whilst migrating this to Gradle, I decided to use an "inclusive" approach, rather than an "exclusive" approach so that things don't get included by accident later on.

I'd like to be able to grab the source code and resources for all of the source sets without having to list the directories explicitly, but I can't get it working.

Here's what I have so far (doesn't even run!):

```
task srcZip(type: Zip) {
    classifier = 'src'
    from projectDir
    include {
        sourceSets.collect {
            it.allSource.asPath
        }
    }
}
```

The ZIP file should end up with folders 'src/main/java/...', 'src/main/resources/...', 'src/test/java/...', etc., and I shouldn't need to re-visit this task when I add more source sets later on.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To get all sources into 1 zip file you can use this:

```
task srcZip(type: Zip) {
    classifier = 'src'
    from sourceSets*.allSource
}
```

It won't give you the directory structure you asked for though. The files from all source sets are put into the same hierarchy.

To get what you asked for you can use this:

```
task srcZip2(type: Zip) {
    classifier = 'src'
    from projectDir
    include 'src/**/*'
}
```

Of course, it doesn't take into account any changes you might make to source directory locations.

Comment: Hmm... Yeah, but it makes me feel kinda... dirty! Thanks for the answer. I'll award you the rep if I don't get an answer which better fits my requirements in a few days. Thanks again.

Comment: I know what you mean. I tried to coax the first form into making the directory structure you want, but couldn't.

Comment: I want to share my customization: add `println "Path to zip: $archivePath.path"` and you'll see path to the produced zip in logs.

Answer (score 8):

So, 21 months later, here's what I did to get this to work (with Gradle 1.2)

```
task srcZip(type: Zip) {
    classifier = 'src'
    from projectDir
    include sourceSets*.allSource.srcDirs*.collect { relativePath(it) }.flatten()
    include 'LICENCE', 'README', 'NOTICE', 'gradlew*'
}
assemble.dependsOn(srcZip)
```

My Groovy-fu is not strong, so I'm sure that horrible bit in the middle could be simplified, but it work for now!

Comment: That should be

include sourceSets*.allSource.srcDirs*.collect { relativePath(it) + "/**/*.*" }.flatten()

otherwise you will just get source folders but not it's contents with Gradle 2.1.

Comment: Hi, I am using a custom gradle plugin project to achieve this but this code(if used directly) doesn't work for me. It gives error on classifier and if I remove, it gives error : No property projectDir found. Any ideas how I can get my code working.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way how we can create the zip of the source code. We can include/exclude files as per requirement. Works in case of custom plugin that I was using and I spent a lot of time figuring out how to make this work. Finally I could achieve it using below code :

```
Task taskSourceZip = project.task("makeSourceZip", type:Zip){
        baseName = "sourceZip"
        from (project.rootDir){
            exclude ('*/*.iml')
            exclude 'sourceZip.zip'
        }
        destinationDir project.rootDir
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Example from one of my projects:

```
task srcZip(type: Zip) {
    classifier = 'src'
    from projectDir
    include 'src/**/*'
    include '*.gradle'
    include 'README.md'
    doLast {
        println "Path to zip: $archivePath.path"
    }
}
```